# Two column layout flow for XSL FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am writing code to create a PDF from an XSL-FO script using Apache-FOP. So, I want the text to be in a two-column format in a single page. So the code currently is in the format.

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="main" column-count="2">
<fo:region-body region-name="main-body"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="main">
<fo:flow>
<fo:block> SOME CONTENT </fo:block>
<fo:block> SOME MORE CONTENT </fo:block>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

So within the fo:block's there are loops which further have nested blocks. So there are a few blocks which gets repeated in every page. So, I thought that the implementation would be such that the left column of the page would be filled before it moves to the right column. However, there seems to be an auto-balancing in which the content gets split to maintain same height or length of the two columns in the page.
Is there any additional attribute to force the content to populate the left column and then move on to the right column?

Comment: Are you showing a full example or do you have a block inside with span="all" on it?

Comment: Yes, I have headings that have span="all" in it.

Comment: Span all will cause an immediate balance of the columns as it should.

Comment: Okay, so there should be a different simple-page-master for the headings to avoid the auto balancing of the columns? Also in around 10% of the cases, the auto balancing is absent. In 1 of 10 pages, the alignment is from left to right. Why is that?